# Let $a,$ $b$ and $c$ are positive numbers.

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

Prove that $$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+\alpha c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{c+\alpha a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{a+\alpha b}}\geq\frac{3}{\sqrt{1+\alpha}}$$ is true for all $\alpha\geq\dfrac{49+9\sqrt{17}}{32}$

I found this inequality proved in this way

let $x,y,z$ satisfies
$\dfrac{a}{b+\alpha c}=\dfrac{x^2}{1+\alpha}$, $\dfrac{b}{c+\alpha a}=\dfrac{y^2}{1+\alpha}$, $\dfrac{c}{a+\alpha b}=\dfrac{z^2}{1+\alpha}$
we have $LHS=\dfrac{x+y+z}{\sqrt{1+\alpha}}$
and by using $$x^2y^2z^2=\dfrac{(1+\alpha)^3abc}{(a+\alpha b)(b+\alpha c)(c+\alpha a)}$$and $$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2=\frac{(1+\alpha)^2(ab(a+\alpha b)+bc(b+\alpha c)+ca(c+\alpha a)}{(a+\alpha b)(b+\alpha c)(c+\alpha a)}$$
we obtain$${(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)x^2y^2z^2+\alpha(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)=(1+\alpha)^2}(*)$$
suppose that $x+y+z<3$ ,there is a $k$ satisfies
$k(x+y+z)=3$ and $k>1$
let $p=kx,q=ky,r=kz$ and use $(*)$ we have
$$(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)p^2q^2r^2+\alpha(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)>(1+\alpha)^2$$
now we try to reach a contradiction by proving$$(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)p^2q^2r^2+\alpha(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)\leq(1+\alpha)^2$$
for all $p,q,r,\ p+q+r=3$
which is equivalent to
$$\alpha^2+\frac{2+p^2q^2r^2-(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)}{1-p^2q^2r^2}\alpha+1\geq0(**)$$
but we have$$\frac{2+p^2q^2r^2-(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)}{1-p^2q^2r^2}\geq\frac{49}{16}$$
since it can be rewritten as
$$\sum{p^6}+6\sum{p^5(q+r)}-\sum{p^4(q^2+r^2)}-12\sum{p^3q^3}+30pqr\sum{p^3}+28pqr\sum{p^2(q+r)}-255p^2q^2r^2\geq0$$
which is schur and muirhead.
so by using quadratic polynomial $(**)$ is true when $$\alpha\geq\frac{49+9\sqrt{17}}{32}$$
thus our assumption is wrong and $x+y+z\geq3$,
$LHS\geq\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{1+\alpha}}$.Done.

Here the step

> $$\alpha^2+\frac{2+p^2q^2r^2-(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)}{1-p^2q^2r^2}\alpha+1\geq0(**)$$
>   but we have$$\frac{2+p^2q^2r^2-(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)}{1-p^2q^2r^2}\geq\frac{49}{16}$$
>   since it can be rewritten as
>   $$\sum{p^6}+6\sum{p^5(q+r)}-\sum{p^4(q^2+r^2)}-12\sum{p^3q^3}+30pqr\sum{p^3}+28pqr\sum{p^2(q+r)}-255p^2q^2r^2\geq0$$
>   which is schur and muirhead.

I did not understood. So tried to break $$\frac{2+p^2q^2r^2-(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)}{1-p^2q^2r^2}\geq\frac{49}{16}$$Which finally comes to $$65p^2q^2r^2 -16\left(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2\right)-17\geq 0$$ Here i am stuck

Comment: Wow.  Of all the specifics of the problem the ones you chose to be pertinent enough to put in the title are:  $a,b,c$ are positive integers.  Yes, that surely will get someone browsing through the titles a clear idea what the question is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By you work we need to prove that:
$$(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)p^2q^2r^2+\alpha(p^2q^2+q^2r^2+r^2p^2)\leq(1+\alpha)^2$$ for positives $p$, $q$ and $r$ such that $p+q+r=3$.

Now, let $p+q+r=3u$, $pq+pr+qr=3v^2$ and $pqr=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\leq0$, where $f$ is a convex function.

But the convex function gets a maximal value for an extreme value of $w^3$, which by $uvw$  happens in the following cases.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $r\rightarrow0^+$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\alpha p^2q^2\leq(1+\alpha)^2.$$ 
Indeed, by AM-GM $$\alpha p^2q^2\leq\alpha\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^4=\frac{81\alpha}{16}$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{81\alpha}{16}\leq(1+\alpha)^2$$ or
$$\alpha^2-\frac{49}{16}\alpha+1\geq0,$$ which gives 
$$\alpha\in\left(-\infty,\frac{49-9\sqrt{17}}{32}\right]\cup\left[\frac{49+9\sqrt{17}}{32},+\infty\right),$$
which is true for $$\alpha\geq \frac{49+9\sqrt{17}}{32}.$$
2. Two variables are equal.

Let $q=p$ and $r=3-2p$, where $0<p<1.5$.

Thus, we need to prove that: 
$$(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)p^4(3-2p)^2+\alpha(p^4+2p^2(3-2p)^2)\leq(1+\alpha)^2$$ or
$$(p-1)^2(1+2(1+\alpha)^2p+3(\alpha^2-4\alpha+1)p^2+4(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)p^3-4(\alpha^2-\alpha+1)p^4)\geq0,$$ which is true for any $0<p<1.5$ and $\alpha\geq\frac{49+9\sqrt{17}}{32}.$

Comment: Sorry i did not accepted this answer because i did not know about uvw mathod. Now i understood that mathod and its strength i liked this answer